# How to increase survivability in battle?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

Some fights in this game can be difficult, frustrating, or at least tedious. Sometimes, it can be difficult to know what the game wants you to do in some battles. How can you know how to approach each enemy/encounter?

Answer (score 1):

This game offers some very helpful tutorial moments in its early stages and provides instructions when you first gain a new ability, but it's not always easy to remember everything in such a fast-paced game. Here are some pointers to help turn the tide in your favor:

- **The more, the merrier!** Your strength and abilities grow as your team's numbers grow. If you're struggling with a fight, look for opportunities earlier in the Operation to gather more recruits. Keep in mind that civilians aren't the only help you can find; enemy foot soldiers can be recruited to join you as well by weakening them (watch for them to stop moving and glow purple-ish) and then wrapping them in a Wonder-Circle.
- **Variety is the spice of life!** Try different Unite Morphs on each enemy to see how you can use them to your advantage; some Morphs may give you a chance to stun/counter an enemy or to expose its weak point. Example: if an enemy has a tail or antenna, try grappling it with a Unite Whip to stagger it.
- **Bigger is better!** Not only do bigger Unite Morphs do more damage, but some of them become more useful as they grow in size. For example, have you ever tried pulling the armor off a Gedie Dough-Goo (big two-legged enemy with spiked armor) while using a super-sized Unite Whip? You might find more chunks of its armor coming undone with each tug!
- **Divide and conquer!** You can have your teammates use their own Unite Morph by pressing X after forming a Wonder-Liner. Micro-managing your team by splitting them into small Morphs each can help thin an otherwise-overwhelming group of smaller enemies before they can swarm you. Plus, it may seem cowardly, but sending your teammates in with a Unite Morph and then backing off to let them fight can help you avoid taking damage if you're struggling to deal with the enemy first-hand.
- **Run rings around everything!** The Wonder-Circle is your friend. Not only does it let you recruit citizens, but you can use it to activate some special locations and get useful items (like reviving withered flower beds), repair damaged areas on a structure, or even pick up random objects in your environment to throw at enemies. (You can even pick up and throw some stunned enemies for lots of damage!)
- **Many hands make light work!** Unite Morphs are a good way to deal hefty damage quickly, but Climb Attacks can be helpful against large enemies. Pile your teammates onto a hulking foe between Morph attacks, and you might find battles ending even faster than before - in your favor. This becomes especially useful when you get the Unite Bomb ability later in the game, as enemies slowed by its effect can't sweep away your comrades as easily once they start a Climb Attack.
- **Know your elements!** There are three primary elements in this game, and each one can be helpful if you know how it affects you. A Unite Hand is not only immune to fire but can be ignited by open flames to deal more damage over time with each successful hit. (PROTIP: Fire also melts ice!) A Unite Sword can be electrified to amplify its damage output. Unite Claw is a special case: it always has the ice element active, and hitting a target repeatedly may eventually encase it in solid ice, rendering it immobile and ripe for the pummeling.
- **Watch and learn!** If you're having trouble dealing with certain enemies, study the patterns that go with each of their attacks. Almost all enemies telegraph their actions to some degree, and recognizing those tell-tale signs can help you time your dodges, blocks, or counterattacks.
- **~P-Ping!~ Pay attention to P-Star! ~Bzzzt!~** His speech pattern may be irritating, but P-Star can provide some helpful tips in areas where the path forward may not be obvious. If you hear his signature beeping while fighting or running around, stop and pay attention to the image that he shows you; it may be the key to progressing in your mission.
- **Hit and run!** Aside from the smaller cannon-fodder types, the units of GEATHJERK won't just sit around and take a beating; they'll dodge around you, raise their defenses, or even break your Unite Morphs with brute force. Don't try to power through these reactions; learn how to subvert them to avoid being caught off-guard. Example: when an enemy turns red, it becomes nearly invulnerable and attacks ruthlessly, so keep your distance until it calms down.
- **Break stuff, get stuff!** There are plenty of destructible objects in each operation, and while you don't always get much from any one in particular, some may give up items that restore your health or Unite Energy in a pinch. Some large enemies also drop these items when defeated. Be on the lookout for large green or yellow orbs, as these hold instant-use items that could give you a second wind in battle.